# How to make Twisted use Python logging?

Tags: python, twisted

I've got a project where I'm using Twisted for my web server.  When exceptions occur (such as network errors), it's printing to the console.

I've already got logging through Python's built-in log module - is there any way to tell the reactor to use that instead?

What's the usual pattern for this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found it.  It's actually quite easy:

```
from twisted.python import log
observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver(loggerName='logname')
observer.start()
```

You just set loggerName to the same logger name that you're using in logging.getLogger().

Comment: Note that you aren't required to use the same loggerName. Using a different one may help distinguish where log messages are coming from and is equivalent to using different loggers in different parts of your application.

Comment: That's a good idea.  What also helps is that I include the thread name in the log message format.  That helps when figuring out where logs are coming from.

Comment: Just FYI the python logging module can block and twisted does not expect that. Better way is to write customer handler in python, that calls sends events to twisted. This way you time python  locking logging to nonblocking one

Comment: @LaKantara Thank you!  But please, can you elaborate that?  Perhaps in a separate answer how this might look like?  (Sorry, I do not have 1++ year to learn everything about twisted, just to be able to understand how that, what you suggest, can be archived, only to be able to integrate some major "twisted infected" source into something like a non-twisted framework.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [twisted.python.log](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/logging.html). For example:

```
from twisted.python import log
log.msg('Hello, world.')
```

Comment: This does work, but only for your own log messages, not the ones generated by twisted and its modules.