# How to use native Python logging or/and Twisted logger for multiple daemon/cron scripts?

Tags: python, linux, logging, twisted, daemon

I use logging to one file with different scripts of one program - such as cron tasks, twisted daemons (HttpServers with some data) etc.

If I use default Python logging in base class such as

```
        import logging
        import logging.handlers
        ....

        self.__fname = open(logname, 'a')
        logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, filename=logname, handler=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler)
        self._log = logging.getLogger(self.__pname)
        self._log.setLevel(loglevel)

        logging.warn('%s %s \033[0m' % (self.__colors[colortype], msg))
```

then it's work normally, sending output of all scripts in one file, but some important part of default twisted log missing - such as info about http request/headers etc

else I use twisted logging such as

```
        from twisted.python.logfile import DailyLogFile
        from twisted.python import log
        from twisted.application.service import Application

        ....

        application = Application("foo")
        log.startLogging(DailyLogFile.fromFullPath(logname))

        print '%s %s \033[0m' % (self.__colors[colortype], msg)
```

then works with additional data, but some trouble with logging from different scripts exists - looks like cron tasks trouble appears. Looks like these cron tasks switch context of output and some part of logging output is missing and not restored

Of, course - cron tasks working without Twisted reactor, but using twisted logging.

What I should do with logging for log all data printed both Twisted/cron parts of app?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not a dupe, but have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493644/how-to-make-twisted-use-python-logging

Comment: Yes I see it, but nothing changing in log when use it

            from twisted.application.service import Application
            application = Application("foo")
            observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver(loggerName='logname')
            observer.start()

            log.startLogging(DailyLogFile.fromFullPath(logname))

Comment: Uughhh.... don't put terminal control codes in your log files!!!  That's your log _viewer's_ job!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point is that you should not use DailyLogFile but use PythonLOggingObserver to redirect the log to standard lib log

```
from twisted.python import log
observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver()
observer.start()
log.msg('%s %s \033[0m' % (self.__colors[colortype], msg))
```

Also you might want to see the example in docs: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/logging.html#auto3